# Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 452 4.3.1 Out of memory

Tags: php, server

Why php sometimes showing me this warning

> mail(): SMTP server response: 452 4.3.1 Out of memory

1. I'm using Shared web hosting service
2. System : Windows
3. memory_limit : 128M
4. Number of Emails sent by script : about 20 emails / day

The script was working just fine for some days, suddenly the warning appears, but now it's disappeared !

Comment: That's the error from the SMTP server, not from PHP, talk to your hosting provider.

Comment: @JonStirling Ok, Can there be any explanations of what happening there ?

Comment: The SMTP server process ran out of memory. I'm not sure what else there is to say....